# Ajax and Json query not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Im having some trouble retieving data using Ajax. Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code? I have a feeling it has something to do with the fact that im using JSON and Ajax in the same function?

**JQuery**

```
function updateImage() {
     var knownid = document.location.hash.substring(1); // remove #     

    $.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
         type: "POST",
         url: "testimagelook.php", //file name
         data: {boxid: knownid},
         success: function(server_response){
            $.getJSON("testimagelook.php", function(data) {             
            var id = data.id;
            document.location.hash = id;

            known_images[id] = [];
            known_images[id] ['name'] = data.name;
            known_images[id] ['average'] = data.average;
            known_images[id] ['votes'] = data.votes;
            known_images[id] ['username'] = data.username;
            known_images[id] ['userid'] = data.userid;

            });
         }
     });

     $('#design').attr('src','img/boxes/'+knownid+'.png');
     $("#lblName").html(known_images[knownid]['name']);
     $('#lblRating').html(known_images[knownid] ['average'] + " (" + known_images[knownid] ['votes'] + ") (<a href='User.php?uid=" + known_images[knownid] ['userid'] + "'>" + known_images[knownid] ['username'] + "</a>)");
}
```

my PHP file that Ajax connects to is as follows:

**PHP**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

if (isset($_POST['boxid']))
{
$knownid = $_POST['boxid'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT b.id as boxid, b.name, b.date_added, u.username, u.id as userid, u.active, b.active, b.active_admin, b.average as average, b.votes as votes FROM BOXES b, USERS u WHERE b.user_id = u.id AND b.id >= $knownid LIMIT 0,1");

$userData = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(array("id" => $userData['boxid'], "name" => $userData['name'], "average" => $userData['average'], "votes" => $userData['votes'], "username" => $userData['username'], "userid" => $userData['userid']));
}
?>
```

Comment: you don't "use json". json's just an encoding/transport format. `.getJSON()` is just a standard GET ajax request, that happens to expect the response to be in JSON format. How is this code not working? wrong answer? crashes something? kicks your dog? As well, you are wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: you should add an `error` callback to the `ajax` options so you can see what the error details are. Also, `$.getJSON` calls `$.ajax` internally, you probably don't want to make the same ajax call twice.

Comment: @MarcB You kick my dog!?

Comment: @jbabey Is there any way you could provide me with some example code as to how to retrieve the data I need without sending two requests?

Comment: @GlenRobson - you only need the ajax request, with the data returned in `server_response`.  The code above makes an ajax call, which waits for a response and then makes the exact same call again.

Comment: @MarcB This code is not working as the value of the lblName element and the lblRating element are not being populated with the data being retrieved by the Ajax call.

Comment: If you want them to be populated with retrieved data, you need to do it in the callback. You're doing it before the AJAX completes.

Comment: Remember, the first A in AJAX stands for _asynchronous_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two requests. Specifying `dataType: 'json'` in the first request tells jQuery to parse the response as JSON.

```
function updateImage() {
     var knownid = document.location.hash.substring(1); // remove #     

    $.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
         type: "POST",
         url: "testimagelook.php", //file name
         data: {boxid: knownid},
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
            var id = data.id;
            document.location.hash = id;   
            known_images[id] = data;
            $("#lblName").html(data.name);
            $('#lblRating').html(data.average + " (" + data.votes + ") (<a href='User.php?uid=" + data.userid + "'>" + data.username + "</a>)");
         }
     });

     $('#design').attr('src','img/boxes/'+knownid+'.png');


}
```

Comment: This looks good however when i change my code to yours everywhere the data should be shown it says 'undefined'

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to fill in `#lblName` and `#lblRating` in the callback.

Comment: I am still getting undefined everywhere

Comment: Oh i worked it out. It is returning the correct information: {"id":"9","name":"Test5","average":"4.83","votes":"63","username":"TestUser","userid":"14"}